# when i use ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer Db.Select<TableA> sometimes Result is TableB's rows or TableA's other rows

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

```
var user =  Db.Single<User>(x => x.Id==1); 
   if(user.Id!=1||user.Id==0)
{logger.Error($"Incorrect result{user.Id}")}
```

can see any result in Log file. 
This problem has troubled me for a long time
And never seen before

Comment: This doesn't make sense, can you [create a stand-alone repro on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=0cd558e817f28f77b974c44c3e12ff6f&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a) or publish a stand-alone example on GitHub? Note: you can [view OrmLite's generated sql](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#beforeexecfilter-and-afterexecfilter-filters) using `OrmLiteUtils.PrintSql()`, also I recommend setting `OrmLiteConfig.ThrowOnError = true` to throw on Exceptions.

Comment: Right it shouldn't, the important focus is on now identifying what the actual issue is, the only way anyone will be able to help is if you can [provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it's impossible to help without being able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, my situation is a bit special, I try to describe it in detail .I think it may not be a problem with the OrmLite. I asked about ado.net System.Data.SqlClient related questions, they did not answer me, so I asked you for help. I tried to use ado.net, without using OrmLite, the problem is still.@mythz

Answer (score 1):

I also think it is possible a concurrency issue. so i code a simple select use ado.net   , the problem is still

```
  string sql = $" select * from where Id=1 ";
                                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString))
                                {
                                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                    connection.Open();
                                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql , connection);
                                    sda.Fill(dt);
                                    connection.Close();
                                    sda.Dispose();
                                    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                    var    user= dt.ToSingleModel<User>();
                                    }
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is difficult to reproduce, and it will only appear after millions of queries. Of course, it may not be so much, there is not much regularity. So I just uploaded the code, and you may not be able to reproduce it.

In order to capture the log, I rewrote SingleById

```
 public T SingleById( int id)
        {
            var result = Db.SingleById<T>(id);
            if (result == null || result.Id != id)
            {
                var first = result.ToIndentedJson();
                result = Db.SingleById<T>(id);
                if (result == null || result.Id != id)
                {
                    result =Db.SingleById<T>(id);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        LogQueryError(first,result, 2);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    LogQueryError(first, result, 1);
                }
            }          
            return result;    
        }

 public static readonly Logger LoggerMustDeal = LogManager.GetLogger("MustDeal");
 public void LogQueryError(string first, IEntityBase entityBase, int level = 1)
        {
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);
            var frames = st.GetFrames();
            foreach (var sf in frames)
            {
                if (System.Diagnostics.StackFrame.OFFSET_UNKNOWN == sf.GetILOffset()) break;
                var fileName = sf.GetFileName();
                if (sf.GetMethod() == null || (!fileName.IsNullOrEmpty() && !fileName.Contains("LastOne")))
                {
                    break;
                }
                var str =
                    $"{fileName} {sf.GetMethod().Name} {sf.GetFileLineNumber()} {sf.GetFileColumnNumber()}";
                LoggerMustDeal.Error($"sqlserver error {str}");
            }


            LoggerMustDeal.Error($"sqlserver error first data {first}");
            LoggerMustDeal.Error($"sqlserver error times {level}  {entityBase.ToIndentedJson()} {Db.ConnectionString}");
            var spId = Db.Single<int>("select @@SPID");
            LoggerMustDeal.Error($"spid:{spId}");
        }
```

now the log  id=219 is the correct result,This just happened in the production environment
And very strangely, **@@SPID return 0  or throw an exception Input string was not in a correct format. Just like select @@spid int but return varchar**

```
2020-04-27 16:28:34.9112 ERROR sqlserver error first data {
  "Name": "",
  "StartTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "EndTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "ActivityType": 0,
  "ActivityRangeType": 0,
  "IsOpen": false,
  "ActivityFlag": null,
  "Timer": 0,
  "State": 2,
  "Id": 3,
  "Delstatus": false,
  "AddTime": "2020-02-04T18:36:03.883",
  "UpdateTime": "2020-04-27T10:04:13.713",
  "MallId": 1
}
2020-04-27 16:28:34.9112 ERROR sqlserver error times 1 {
  "Name": "test",
  "StartTime": "2020-04-18T00:00:00",
  "EndTime": "2020-04-19T00:00:00",
  "ActivityType": 1,
  "ActivityRangeType": 1,
  "IsOpen": true,
  "ActivityFlag": "test",
  "Timer": 0,
  "State": 2,
  "Id": 219,
  "Delstatus": false,
  "AddTime": "2020-04-13T17:38:48.83",
  "UpdateTime": "2020-04-13T17:38:48.83",
  "MallId": 15
} server=xxxx;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;database=xxxx;max pool size=40000;Pooling=true;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code dump isn't useful on its own, would really need to be able to build/run a stand-alone repro. How is this being called? e.g. in a WebRequest/ServiceStack Service? Can you confirm you're not sharing the `Db` connection in more than 1 thread? Can you try using the [BeforeExecFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#beforeexecfilter-and-afterexecfilter-filters) to log the executed query along with the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`.

Comment: i tried Multi-threaded access Db,  will throw excepiton direct .Now i try  BeforeExecFilter  and Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId ,I will feedback if there is a result

Comment: Note: the same Db connection shouldn't be shared in multiple threads, i.e. each thread needs to open & use their own Db connection. I just can't think of anything other than a race condition/data corruption issue. Maybe the generated SQL will yield further insight, but would need to match the logs with the same ThreadId.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting thing happened today
In redis

```
key                    value
Urn:sid               {"__type":"UserSession"}               
OrderPaySettle        {"__type":"ServiceInterface.SettleOrder"}

Thread A Redis.Get<UserSession>("Urn:sid")    at 2020-04-29 06:27:53.0000
Thread B Redis.Get<object>("OrderPaySettle")  at 2020-04-29 06:27:53.8009
var item = Redis.Get<object>("OrderPaySettle")
```

then we found item's type is UserSession in Log file

A few days ago, through log analysis, the database was almost the same. The wrong result was queried, usually the result that another thread just queried and got

Does it feel like a memory or network layer problem?
What is your opinion on this? @mythz

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been solved.

In my code , There will be many such examples , one api service resolve any other service and every service will open a dbconnction , and dbconnction   dispose on service dispose . so there may be many opened dbconnections at the same time.

```
public object Post(RequestA request)
  {
    using var servceA=ResolveService<ServiceA>();
    using var servceB=ResolveService<ServiceB>();
    using var servceC=ResolveService<ServiceC>();
    .......
    using var servceN=ResolveService<ServiceN>();

    ...
    ...
  }
```

I created the DAL layer ,dbconnction will dispose after exec

```
public T Single(SqlExpression<T> exp)
  {
    using var db = HostContext.AppHost.GetDbConnection(Request);
    var result = db.Single(exp);
    return result;
   }
```

Since this change, there have been no problems for more than 20 consecutive days
But I still don’t know where the problem is.
May be many opened dbconnections at the same time will abnormal ?